# Combining rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I record Start and End times in SQL whenever something happens to a record, basically a user opens a screen containing the information on a record, and I want to see how long the screen was opened.

I record the start time, and the end together with the stage the case is currently in for that case in a linked table similar to this:

```
| Id        | Reference   | Stage | StartTime                   | EndTime                     | 
| 1         | 123456789   | NEW   | 2015-03-30 16:04:39.8100000 | NULL                        |                  
| 2         | 123456789   | NEW   | NULL                        | 2015-03-30 16:06:44.3830000 |
| 3         | 123456789   | VAL   | 2015-03-30 16:09:00.3800000 | NULL                        |
| 4         | 123456789   | VAL   | NULL                        | 2015-03-30 16:11:04.9870000 |
| 5         | 123456789   | CAP   | 2015-03-30 16:20:25.7900000 | NULL                        |
| 6         | 123456789   | CAP   | NULL                        | 2015-03-30 16:21:12.1130000 |
| 7         | 123456789   | CAP   | 2015-03-30 16:22:40.4930000 | NULL                        |
| 8         | 123456789   | CAP   | NULL                        | 2015-03-30 16:29:02.5030000 |
| 9         | 123456789   | CAP   | 2015-03-30 16:29:17.8970000 | NULL                        |
| 10        | 123456789   | CAP   | NULL                        | 2015-03-30 16:55:13.8870000 |
| 11        | 123456789   | CAP   | 2015-03-30 16:56:20.2230000 | NULL                        |
| 12        | 123456789   | CAP   | NULL                        | 2015-03-30 16:56:40.3830000 |
```

I've been playing around but was unable to get the desired result:

```
| Id        | Reference   | Stage | StartTime                   | EndTime                     | 
| 1         | 123456789   | NEW   | 2015-03-30 16:04:39.8100000 | 2015-03-30 16:06:44.3830000 |  
| 3         | 123456789   | VAL   | 2015-03-30 16:09:00.3800000 | 2015-03-30 16:11:04.9870000 |
| 5         | 123456789   | CAP   | 2015-03-30 16:20:25.7900000 | 2015-03-30 16:21:12.1130000 |
| 7         | 123456789   | CAP   | 2015-03-30 16:22:40.4930000 | 2015-03-30 16:29:02.5030000 |
| 9         | 123456789   | CAP   | 2015-03-30 16:29:17.8970000 | 2015-03-30 16:55:13.8870000 |
| 11        | 123456789   | CAP   | 2015-03-30 16:56:20.2230000 | 2015-03-30 16:56:40.3830000 |
```

How can I combine the data (Start and End time) in this case?

Comment: You have to place condition while inserting EndTime whether startTime is exist for this reference ? and just update the row. and as per your scenario you should update table for Endtime.

Comment: That was my first approach, but I wanted to keep a nice audit trail, and when a screen was opened multiple times the update messed around with the reference. So I went the other route, which made things a lot more difficult, but was working properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select StartTime rows and with an inner select fill EndTime:

```
SELECT Id, Reference, Stage, StartTime, 
           (SELECT t1i.EndTime FROM Table1 t1i WHERE t1.Stage = t1i.Stage And t1i.StartTime IS NULL
           And t1i.Id = (SELECT min(t1ii.Id) FROM t1ii WHERE t1ii.StartTime IS NULL And t1ii.Stage = t1.Stage And t1ii.Id > t1.Id) )
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.EndTime IS NULLL
```

Comment: This has actually provided me with a solution -
(SELECT TOP 1 t1.EndTime 
 FROM vCISStartEndTime1 t1 
 WHERE t1.[Queue] = t.[Queue] 
  AND t1.Reference = t.Reference 
  AND t1.StartTime IS NULL 
  AND t1.Id > t.Id
) 'EndTime'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT [Id], [Reference], [Stage], [StartTime],lead(EndTime) OVER (ORDER BY    ID) AS NewEndDate FROM yourTablename 
) tbl
WHERE id % 2 = 1
```

**EDIT**: This query will work in SQL Server 2012 and above versions

You can use below query if you are using older versions of SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT t.[Id], t.[Reference], t.[Stage], t.[StartTime], tnext.[EndTime]
FROM dates t INNER JOIN
 dates tnext
 ON t.id = tnext.id - 1
) tbl
WHERE id % 2 = 1
```

Comment: The EDIT broke my world. I need this to work on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @JohanAspeling, the answer is updated to work on SQL Server 2008 R2  and older versions of SQL Server

Comment: Hmm, the problem with this solution is that it assumes the EndTime for the corresponding StartTime will always be directly after the StartTime entry, which is the case in my example but will not always be the case in my situation. Still keeping it as the answer as it will technically solve my problem if I sort it by Reference, and Queue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT MIN(id), reference, stage, MAX(startTime), MAX(endTime)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY reference, stage
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: This wouldnt work as a user can open the screen multiple times in the same stage, and this only caters for the screen being opened once on each stage.. :(